# Remote access to a machine without using customer network

Tags: remote

I have a trouble with a machine dropped at a customer's factory and the customer doesn't want to physically connect the machine to his own network (administration, security leaks, ...).

For maintenance or statistics purposes, I would like to connect to this machine and use a remote desktop... How would I do that ?

Are there devices that will allow me to connect to my server without having to connect to a wired network ? (using GPRS services or related stuff ?)

Any suggestions ?

Note : My customer doesn't mind us having a connection to our devices, he simply doesn't want its network to be part of the connection process.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought was to suggest that you use a USB modem however this can be costly so a wired connection purchased from the telco would probably be a better alternative.

These are costs that the customer will have to pay ultimately.

After reading your question many times I cannot quite understand the following statement:
Note : My customer doesn't mind us having a connection to our devices, he simply doesn't want its network to be part of the connection process.

Routing can protect his network and also allow you access to the remote machine. Ultimately this is the better solution?

Comment: Routing would be the best solution. Definitely. Some of our customers don't mind us using their network to access our machines. But some customers don't want our machines to be physically connected to their network...

Comment: Not understanding the situation completely makes it difficult. Using a USB modem is not going to be easy as you face having the issue of dynamic IP's plus many others. This is not the route I would go. Wired network is better in the long run.

Comment: Yes, but a teamviewer with a static account installed on my machine would solve the ip problem... It's not perfect because, as you said, the customer will have to pay... But that's a solution, thank you for your help !

Comment: I am glad my suggestions helped :)